# what's the proposal of "DependsOn" on Prism Library

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

I'did look in several places to find more information about "DependsOn" property of `ModuleInfo` Type with not success.

I did guess that is relative to load other modules that depends of this one, for exemple:

I have a `moduleA` with it's property `InitializatioMode` set as `Prism.Modularity.InitializationMode.WhenAvailable`

also have `moduleB` with it's property `InitializatioMode` set as
`Prism.Modularity.InitializationMode.OnDemand`

but the moduleA "dependsOn" moduleB, so I did set it's attribute `[ModuleDependency("moduleB")]` assuming that with this config will be able to navigate from `moduleA` to `moduleB` in sweet way, but it's not was the expected behavior, when the navigation is executed, nothing happens.

Someone can give more information to me figure out what's this config sets ?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "navigation"? Module dependency is just about load order of modules.

Comment: In the scenario described above, navigation is the action to switch between pages, in that case, I want means the action to navigate to any page embed in `moduleA` to any page embed in `moduleB`, in summary navigate between pages in differente modules

Comment: For navigation, it's completely irrelevant in which module a page resides.

Comment: Yes, but I'm looking for more information about the proposal of "dependsOn" property.

Comment: "DependsOn" guarantees that the module(s) that you depend on are loaded first.